# Optaplanner:Add / remove constraints dynamically

Tags: xml, spring-boot, spring-mvc, java-stream, optaplanner

I have such a problem. I need to generate two different plans according to the current several entity objects.

My planned order entity class：

```
@Data
@PlanningEntity
public class PlanOrder  implements Serializable {

@PlanningId
private String id;


private String drawingNo;


private String itemName;


private String jdJhzl;


private String actualQuantity1;


private String pddj1;


private String actualQuantity2;


private String rsdj1;



private String actualQuantity3;


private String opdj1;


private String actualQuantity4;


private String trdj1;


private String annual;


private String monthly;


private String materialCode;


private String pa8;


private String tosell2;


private String status;


private ProductionLine productionLine;

@PlanningVariable(valueRangeProviderRefs={'productionLineRange'})
public ProductionLine getProductionLine() {
    return productionLine;
}

public void setProductionLine(ProductionLine productionLine) {
    this.productionLine = productionLine;
}

public PlanOrder(String id, String drawingNo, String itemName, String jdJhzl, String actualQuantity1, String pddj1, String actualQuantity2, String rsdj1, String actualQuantity3, String opdj1, String actualQuantity4, String trdj1, String annual, String monthly, String materialCode, String pa8, String tosell2, String status, ProductionLine productionLine) {
    this.id = id;
    this.drawingNo = drawingNo;
    this.itemName = itemName;
    this.jdJhzl = jdJhzl;
    this.actualQuantity1 = actualQuantity1;
    this.pddj1 = pddj1;
    this.actualQuantity2 = actualQuantity2;
    this.rsdj1 = rsdj1;
    this.actualQuantity3 = actualQuantity3;
    this.opdj1 = opdj1;
    this.actualQuantity4 = actualQuantity4;
    this.trdj1 = trdj1;
    this.annual = annual;
    this.monthly = monthly;
    this.materialCode = materialCode;
    this.pa8 = pa8;
    this.tosell2 = tosell2;
    this.status = status;
    this.productionLine = productionLine;
}

public PlanOrder() {
}
}
```

My inventory entity class：

```
@Data

public class Inventory implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;


private Long id;


private String ckbh;


private String cklx;


private String wlbh;


private Double kcsl;


private Double kcfzsl;


private Integer operate;
}
```

My client entity class：

```
@Data
public class ProductionLine implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@PlanningId
private String id;


private String onlyKey;


private String lineId;


private String line;


private String itemNumber;


private String itemName;


private String dailyEnergy;
}
```

My plan assignment class：

```
@PlanningSolution
public class PlanAssignment{

@PlanningId
private Long id;


private HardSoftScore score;


@ValueRangeProvider(id = 'productionLineRange')
@ProblemFactCollectionProperty
private List<ProductionLine> productionLineList;


@ValueRangeProvider(id = 'planOrderRange')
@PlanningEntityCollectionProperty
private List<PlanOrder> planOrderList;


public PlanAssignment(List<ProductionLine> productionLineList, List<PlanOrder> planOrderList) {
    this.productionLineList = productionLineList;
    this.planOrderList = planOrderList;
}

public PlanAssignment() {
}

@PlanningScore
public HardSoftScore getScore() {
    return score;
}

public Long getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(Long id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public void setScore(HardSoftScore score) {
    this.score = score;
}

public List<ProductionLine> getProductionLineList() {
    return productionLineList;
}

public void setProductionLineList(List<ProductionLine> productionLineList) {
    this.productionLineList = productionLineList;
}

public List<PlanOrder> getPlanOrderList() {
    return planOrderList;
}

public void setPlanOrderList(List<PlanOrder> planOrderList) {
    this.planOrderList = planOrderList;
}
}
```

My constraint implementation class：

```
public class PlanConstraintProvider implements ConstraintProvider {


@Override
public Constraint[] defineConstraints(ConstraintFactory constraintFactory) {
    return new Constraint[]{
            yarnTypeMatch(constraintFactory),
            clientLevel_used(constraintFactory)
    };
}


private Constraint yarnTypeMatch(ConstraintFactory constraintFactory){
    return constraintFactory.from(PlanOrder.class)
            .filter(planOrder ->planOrder.getProductionLine()!=null)
            .filter(planOrder-> !planOrder.getProductionLine().getItemName().equals(planOrder.getItemName()))
            .penalizeConfigurable('yarn type match', HardSoftScore.ofHard(10000));

}



private  Constraint clientLevelUsed(ConstraintFactory constraintFactory){
  
    return constraintFactory.from(Client.class)
            .ifExists(PlanOrder.class,
                    Joiners.equal(client -> client,PlanOrder::getPa8 ))
            .penalizeConfigurable('client level used',
                    HardSoftScore.ONE_HARD,
                    client->Integer.parseInt(client.getClientLevel()));
}
}
```

My constraintconfiguration annotation class：

```
@ConstraintConfiguration
public class PlanConstraintConfiguration {

@ConstraintWeight('yarn type match')
public HardSoftScore yarnTypeMatch = HardSoftScore.ofHard(1);

@ConstraintWeight('client level used')
public HardSoftScore clientLevelUsed = HardSoftScore.ofHard(2);

}
```

XML configuration：

```
<solver>

<solutionClass>com.zbxx.iem.scheduling.domain.PlanAssignment</solutionClass>
<entityClass>com.zbxx.iem.scheduling.domain.PlanOrder</entityClass>


<scoreDirectorFactory>
 <constraintProviderClass>...solver.PlanConstraintProvider</constraintProviderClass>
</scoreDirectorFactory>

<termination>
    <secondsSpentLimit>10</secondsSpentLimit>
</termination>
```

Controller call：

```
   SolverFactory<PlanAssignment> solverFactory = 
    SolverFactory.createFromXmlResource('planConfiguration.xml');
    Solver<PlanAssignment> solver = solverFactory.buildSolver();

    PlanAssignment planAssignment = new PlanAssignment(productionLineList, planOrderList);
    PlanAssignment solve = solver.solve(planAssignment);
```

The implementation of my idea is: users select different constraints in UI interface and pass them to solver together with parameters. Solver dynamically loads different constraints and starts to solve them according to the constraints transferred，The implementation of my idea is: users select different constraints in UI interface and pass them to solver together with parameters. Solver dynamically loads different constraints and starts to solve them according to the constraints transferred，The reason why I do this is that I don't need to consider the change of semi-finished product inventory and some other variables in monthly planning, but I need to consider the change of semi-finished product inventory and other variables in weekly planning

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at `@ConstraintConfiguration` and `@ConstraintWeight` in the documentation. It's easy to disable constraints by setting their constraint weight to HardSoftScore.ZERO.